# GetBinaryType() fails with a last error of ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

Tags: winapi

EDIT:

The `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` error was not caused by the call to `GetBinaryType()` but by an earlier call to `EnumProcessModules()`, that was attempting to acquire the full path of the executable for a process to pass to `GetBinaryType()`, that failed. There was exception chaining occurring which I missed and that set the error message of the exception to the same error message in the original post but retained the OS error code of `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`.

---

This function is called from within a 32-bit Windows Service. I have searched the internet and stackoverflow and found no other instance where `GetBinaryType()` failed and `GetLastError()` returned `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`:

> Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

A possibility I considered was that `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` was being set by an earlier WINAPI call and `GetBinaryType()` does not `SetLastError()` correctly. I attempted to reproduce this by:

- executing it with the path of a file that does not exist
- executing it with the path of a non-executable file
- executing it with the path of a file that denies access

with no success (I called `SetLastError(ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY);` prior to each of the attempts): each of these attempts produced the expected result.

The code snippet is:

```
std::string full_exe_path =
        a_impl->exe_installation_dir + "\\" + a_impl->exe_name;

DWORD bin_type;
if (FALSE == GetBinaryType(full_exe_path.c_str(), &bin_type))
{
    throw Base_exception(
        __LINE__,
        __FILE__,
        "Failed to get binary type for " + a_impl->exe_name);
        // Optional argument here that defaults to GetLastError()
}
```

Does anyone know, or have any suggestions, as to the cause of this?

*Note: this is happening on a machine that I do not have access to (and works on over 99% of the machines on which the Windows Service is running)*

Comment: What version of Windows is it, and is the OS 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit, its either XP or 7 - can't confirm that until Monday.

Comment: FYI- I ran your code against every exe on two machines (Win7 x64 and XP x86) with no ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY errors.  I tried it compiled as both 32- and 64-bit.  This leads me to suspect that being a service has something to do with it.

Comment: @CareyGregory, thanks for your efforts. The other thought I had was that it was reading across the network, but I was unable to reproduce.

Comment: @CareyGregory, updated question with cause. Sorry to have wasted your time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this right now so the following is a bit speculative :-(

It is really hard to be sure what is causing what you see - AFAIK you need to check the following possibilities:

- Windows Service
  In which user/context is the service running ?
  Since Windows Vista MS has applied several changes to improve security that changed behaviour for example when accessing a network share from a Windows Service!
- Bitness
  `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` can happen esp. when the bitness of your application differs from the bitness of the file you are checking.
- .NET files (EXE/DLL)
  `GetBinaryType()` can behave strangely if the file you are checking happens to be a .NET file.
- Virus scanner etc.
  Any virus scanner etc. can interfer in strange ways with `GetBinaryType()`.
- rootkit infection and similar
  This can give really some strange results since no rootkit is perfect...
- virtual machine
  IF the Windows Service is hosted inside a virtual machine I had several strange experiences with network access.

Another point you could check is whether the behaviour is the same when running this code from a "normal application" - this could give you a clue whether the "Windows Service/Network share" has anything to do with it.

Also check whether you can open the respective file (readonly, no locks) and what [`GetFileType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns in that case.

Comment: +1 Thanks for these suggestions. Will take me awhile to get through them but will let you know, whether successful or not.

Comment: @hmjd you are welcome :-) Any results from your tests so far ?

Comment: none so far. If any of these eventually turn out to be the answer I will restart the bounty (if I can) and ensure credit were credit is due. :) Cheers.

Comment: @hmjd whether it is any of the above or something completely different - I hope you find it, good luck :-)

Comment: I will let you know if I find it. You''ll probably hear my shout of joy before I post back here...

Comment: updated question with cause. Sorry to have wasted your time. Thanks again.